# How can I obtain the quantity of results from a search term using the bing search api?

Tags: python, bing-api

I am able to get the results, but I instead want to get the number of findings returned for a specific date instead of the findings themselves, and I can't seem to figure out what query to run to get a table of the results.

```
subscription_key = "xxx"
assert subscription_key

search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search"
search_term = "Search term"

import requests

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key}
params = {"q": search_term, "textDecorations": True, "textFormat": "HTML"}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()

from IPython.display import HTML

{
  "_type": "News",
  "readLink": "https://<host>/api/v7.0/news/search?q=Sports",
  "queryContext": {
  "originalQuery": "Search Term"
  },
  "totalEstimatedMatches": 118000,
  "value": [. . .]
}
```

I tried this with what I found on the Microsoft help page, but it's giving me a value ". . ." not found, and I'm not sure what to adjust.